# Implementing custom MATLAB functions in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I would like to use a custom MATLAB function in Simulink. So far I have done it by placing an embedded MATLAB function block. However, if the custom function contains another custom function the compile process fails.

Here is the example of function I am trying to embed in the simulation:

```
function [c, d, iterationsCount] = decodeLDPC(y, H, variance)
Lci = initializeLq(y, H, variance);
Lr = getLr(Lci);
[Lq, c] = getLq(Lci, H, Lr);
iterationsCount = 1;

while(sum(mod(c * H', 2)) ~= 0)
    Lr = getLr(Lq);
    [Lq, c] = getLq(Lq, H, Lr);
    iterationsCount = iterationsCount + 1;
end;
G = getGeneratorMatrix(H);
d = c/G;
```

where `initializeLq` and `getLr` are custom functions as well.

Is there a method to implement the above function in the simulation?

Comment: I think MikeT's answer is correct, but I offer this to you: don't use an embedded MATLAB function block in your model because this block causes the model to run very slowly.

Comment: If your model is running slowly, you might want to wrap the EML block with a stateflow diagram.This will eliminate the copying of inputs and outputs on each time-step that can make EML functions outside of stateflow diagrams (in older versions of MATLAB, at least) less efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the command **eml.extrinsic** to call any external MATLAB functions from an EML block.  For example, you can put this at the top of your EML function,

```
eml.extrinsic('getLr', 'initializeLq');
```

to allow those functions to be called.  For more information, see the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/eml/ug/bq1h2z8-34.html#bq1h2z9-38)